# How to resolve error "non static method 'getDeviceId()' cannot be referenced by static context"

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get Device Id in following code

```
    public String getDevId() {
        String devId=android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        return devId;
    }
```

But it is saying "non static method 'getDeviceId()' cannot be referenced by static context"

Comment: Firstly clear up your Core Java.

Comment: I did tryTelephonyManager xx= new TelephonyManager(); but it is saying "TelephonyManager()" is not public

Comment: Include your logcat so we can see what's going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public String getDeviceId(Context context){
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
}
```

Comment: It is giving error can not resolve getSystemService in java.lang.string

Comment: you need a context to access getSystemService

Comment: why did u directly jump to TelephonyManager. first start with [Introduction to Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Comment: Hmm I'm new to android. I was just trying. thanks.